# Swift Convert a three digit Base64 number to Int

Tags: swift

I have a max 3 character value written in base64

I would like to convert to Integer

so "A" = 0, "a" =26 and "/" = 63

```
 0:A   16:Q   32:g   48:w
 1:B   17:R   33:h   49:x
 2:C   18:S   34:i   50:y
 3:D   19:T   35:j   51:z
 4:E   20:U   36:k   52:0
 5:F   21:V   37:l   53:1
 6:G   22:W   38:m   54:2
 7:H   23:X   39:n   55:3
 8:I   24:Y   40:o   56:4
 9:J   25:Z   41:p   57:5
10:K   26:a   42:q   58:6
11:L   27:b   43:r   59:7
12:M   28:c   44:s   60:8
13:N   29:d   45:t   61:9
14:O   30:e   46:u   62:+
15:P   31:f   47:v   63:/
```

I would like to use something like

```
Int("Cat", radix: 64)
```

But the max allowed is radix:36

Is there something elsewhere built-in or do I need to write my own conversion routine?

An example I want the value "Cat" = 45*64^0 + 26*64^1 + 2*64^2 = 9901

Comment: Maybe you should remove that wikipedia article that is about Base64 encoding and not about Base64 integers which is what you want to use. There is nothing you can use in the library because usually we write numbers as case insensitive (that's why radix=36 is the max).

Comment: Did you mean `"a" = 26` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sulthan notes, this isn't what most people mean by "Base64" which is a 6-bit encoding packed into 8-bit bytes. This is an unpacked version which I've never seen used in practice. But you can work this out the same way you'd work out any radix, by finding each symbol in a symbol-mapping, and shifting the current value, and then adding the new place value. While it's probably not needed, I've expanded this to FixedWidthInteger rather than Int. This approach will work for an arbitrary radix and an arbitrary set of symbols.

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    init?(unpackedBase64 string: String) {
        let symbols = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/")

        var result = Self.zero
        for char in string {
            result *= Self(symbols.count)
            guard let placeValue = symbols.firstIndex(of: char) else { return nil }
            result += Self(placeValue)
        }
        self = result
    }
}

Int(unpackedBase64: "Cat") // 9901
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off using standard base 64 padding, but if you don't get to do that, you can still rely on a lot:

*Note: This should give you an idea of what to do, but it doesn't support integer types smaller than 24 bits. You can improve that, or at least change it from `FixedWidthInteger`, which is too broad otherwise.*

```swift
extension FixedWidthInteger {
  init?(unpaddedBase64Encoded string: String) {
    guard
      case let zeroPaddingToReach3ByteMultiple =
        String(repeating: "A", count: 4 - string.count % 4),
      let data = Data(base64Encoded: zeroPaddingToReach3ByteMultiple + string)
    else { return nil }

    let zeroPaddingToFillMemory = Array(
      repeating: 0 as UInt8,
      count: Self.bitWidth / UInt8.bitWidth - data.count
    )

    self =
      (Data(zeroPaddingToFillMemory) + data)
      .withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Self.self).bigEndian }
  }
}
```

```swift
Int(unpaddedBase64Encoded: "Cat") // 9901
UInt32(unpaddedBase64Encoded: "A") // 0
```

And if you need the reverse:

```swift
extension String {
  init?<Integer: FixedWidthInteger>(unpaddedBase64Encoding integer: Integer) {
    if integer == 0 {
      self = "A"
      return
    }

    let fourCharactersBitCount = 4 * 6
    let maxFourCharactersCount = Integer.bitWidth / fourCharactersBitCount

    guard integer < 1 << (fourCharactersBitCount * maxFourCharactersCount)
    else { return nil }

    let
      fourCharactersByteCount = fourCharactersBitCount / UInt8.bitWidth,
      maxCharacterCount = maxFourCharactersCount * fourCharactersByteCount

    self.init(
      withUnsafeBytes(of: integer.bigEndian) {
        Data( $0.suffix(maxCharacterCount) )
        .base64EncodedString()
        .drop { $0 == "A" }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
String(unpaddedBase64Encoding: 2 << 12 | 26 << 6 | 45) // "Cat"
String(unpaddedBase64Encoding: 0) // "A"
String(unpaddedBase64Encoding: 1 as UInt16) // nil.
```

Comment: I loved this answer but chose Rob's because this is more complex (& clever) and also does not work for larger values as is.